Issue with Placeholder Text in Custom NumberInput Component using React
I have created a custom NumberInput component in React and integrated it with Storybook. The component works mostly as expected, but I'm encountering a couple of issues:
When I type the - or + sign, the placeholder text is still visible inside the input field.
When I use the increment arrows to increase or decrease the number, the placeholder text behaves unexpectedly.
When I clear the value using the backspace key, the placeholder text does not reappear even though there's no value in the input
Here's the relevant code for my NumberInput component and its Storybook story
NumberInput.tsx
import { ChevronDownFilled, ChevronUpFilled } from '@kolaveri/icons'
import { ChangeEvent, forwardRef, useImperativeHandle, useRef } from 'react'
import { Input, type InputProps } from '@/shared'
import {
  buttonClassName,
  inputClassName,
  wrapperClassName,
} from './NumberInput.cva'

export interface Props extends Omit<InputProps, 'type'> {
  defaultValue?: number
  value?: number
  classNames?: InputProps['classNames'] & { innerWrapper?: string }
}

type Component = React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<
  Props & React.RefAttributes<HTMLInputElement>
>

const ForwardRefExoticComponent = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, Props>(
  (props, ref) => {
    const { className, classNames = {}, ...remainingProps } = props
    const innerRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)

    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => innerRef.current as HTMLInputElement)

    const handleChange = () => {
      remainingProps.onChange &&
        remainingProps.onChange({
          type: 'number',
          target: { value: innerRef.current?.value },
        } as ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>)
    }

    return (
      <div
        className={wrapperClassName({
          className: [className, classNames?.wrapper],
        })}
      >
        <Input
          className={inputClassName({
            className: classNames?.innerWrapper,
          })}
          classNames={{
            ...classNames,
            input: classNames?.input,
          }}
          ref={ref || innerRef}
          type="number"
          style={{
            appearance: 'textfield',
            MozAppearance: 'textfield',
          }}
          {...remainingProps}
        >
          <button
            tabIndex={-1}
            className={buttonClassName({ position: 'top' })}
            onMouseDown={(e) => {
              if (document.activeElement === innerRef.current) {
                e.preventDefault()
              } else {
                /* Do focus on input */
              }
            }}
            onClick={() => {
              innerRef.current?.focus()
              innerRef.current?.stepUp()
              handleChange()
            }}
            type="button"
          >
            <ChevronUpFilled size="md" variant="light" />
          </button>
          <button
            tabIndex={-1}
            className={buttonClassName({ position: 'bottom' })}
            onMouseDown={(e) => {
              if (document.activeElement === innerRef.current) {
                e.preventDefault()
              } else {
                /* Do focus on input */
              }
            }}
            onClick={() => {
              innerRef.current?.focus()
              innerRef.current?.stepDown()
              handleChange()
            }}
            type="button"
          >
            <ChevronDownFilled size="md" variant="light" />
          </button>
        </Input>
      </div>
    )
  }
)

ForwardRefExoticComponent.displayName = 'NumberInput'

const NumberInput = {
  ...ForwardRefExoticComponent,
} as Component

export default NumberInput

NumberInput.stories.tsx
import { Meta, StoryObj } from '@storybook/react'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { Code, NumberInput } from '@/components'

const meta: Meta<typeof NumberInput> = {
  title: 'forms/NumberInput',
  component: NumberInput,
  tags: ['autodocs'],
}

export default meta
type Story = StoryObj<typeof NumberInput>

export const Default: Story = {
  name: '[0] default',
  args: {
    name: 'currentPrice',
    placeholder: 'i.e. 6.99',
    label: 'Current price (EUR)',
  },
  render: (args) => {
    const [price, setPrice] = useState<number>()
    return (
      <div className="max-w-sm">
        <NumberInput
          {...args}
          value={price}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setPrice(Number(e.target.value))
          }}
        />
        <Code object={{ [args.name]: price }} />
      </div>
    )
  },
}


Steps to Reproduce:

Use the provided NumberInput component in a Storybook story.
Type - or + in the input field and observe the placeholder text.
Use the increment arrows to change the value and observe the behavior.
Clear the value using backspace and observe the placeholder text behavior.

Type - or + in the input field
enter image description here
Clear the value using backspace and observe the placeholder text behavior
enter image description here
Expected Behavior:

The placeholder text should not be visible when typing a - or + sign.
The placeholder text should behave consistently with the increment arrows.
The placeholder text should reappear when the input field is cleared.


you can change NumberInput component like this.
const handleChange = () => {
  remainingProps.onChange &&
    remainingProps.onChange({
      type: 'number',
      target: { value: innerRef.current?.value },
    } as ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>)

  // Check if the input value is empty and show placeholder text accordingly
  if (!innerRef.current?.value) {
    innerRef.current?.setAttribute('placeholder', remainingProps.placeholder || '')
  } else {
    innerRef.current?.removeAttribute('placeholder')
  }
}
return (
<Input
      className={inputClassName({
        className: classNames?.innerWrapper,
      })}
      classNames={{
        ...classNames,
        input: classNames?.input,
      }}
      ref={ref || innerRef}
      type="number"
      style={{
        appearance: 'textfield',
        MozAppearance: 'textfield',
      }}
      {...remainingProps}
    >
      {/* Your button components */}
    </Input>
)

